# How to put object in ternary conditional?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**CODE:**

```
var React = require('react');
var Ingredient = require('./Ingredient.jsx')
var Recipe = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            showIngredients: false
        };
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
            showIngredients: !this.state.showIngredients
        });
    },
    render: function() {

        var i = 0;

        var ingredientsList = this.props.ingredients.map(function(item) {
            i++;
            return <Ingredient key={i} name={item}/>;
        });

        return (
            <table>
                <tbody>
                    <tr className="recipeName" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                        <td>{this.props.name}</td>
                    </tr>
                    {this.state.showIngredients ? {ingredientsList} : null }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = Recipe;
```

This generates the following error:

> main.js:18463 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: Objects are not
>   valid as a React child (found: object with keys {ingredientsList}). If
>   you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or
>   wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.
>   Check the render method of `Recipe`.

Comment: what is Ingredient here. tbody element should be tr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `{}`, that is not required here, Write it like this:

```
{this.state.showIngredients ? ingredientsList : null }
```

Or use a `div` or `tr` or any other `html element` and `render` the `ingredientsList` inside that, like this:

```
{this.state.showIngredients ? <tr> {ingredientsList} </tr> : null }
```

**Reason**: `{}` are required to put `js` code inside `html` elements, when you are using `ternary operator` you are already inside `js` no need of using `{}`.

Check the example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    render() {
       let a = [1,2,4].map(el=> <div key ={el}>{el}</div>)

       return (
           <div>
               {1 == 1 ? a : null}
               {1 == 1 ? <div> {a} </div> : null}
           </div>
       )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='container' />
```

Comment: Mayank, div is not valid tbody element.

Comment: @Ved thanks for pointing out that, edited the ques, i just wanted to give him the idea how to render `ingredientsList` :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're trying to render a plain JS object as a React element. You *can* render a plain JS array if its entries are React elements, which is what your `ingredientsList` looks like. If you remove the brackets from around this array, I think this should work.

(i.e. change `{ingredientsList}` to `ingredientsList`)